# Following a company page sends me to a JSON response page

Tags: bug, status-review, user-experience, companies-page

When I'm trying to follow a company page on Stack Overflow, it redirects me to a new page containing a JSON response:

```json
{"following":false,"success":true}
```

I think there's an error with dealing with the response instead of returning a notification or alert.

Comment: What URL are you accessing?

Comment: I just tried to follow this company, then it's redirect me here:

`https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/company/pluralsight/unfollow`

Comment: Not sure how you found that, but when I try to access that URL I get a normal looking  page with the text: **We have shut down Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story as of April 1, 2022**. So this is probably *by-design*

Comment: eh, i'd imagine clicking "follow" on the existing company ads going to a json result would in fact not be "by design", given it's still a product they sell and advertise, as opposed to Jobs which was shut down.

Comment: it appeared to me on the right panel in stack overflow with a title check out these companies

Comment: What browser are you using? That URL is where [the form action for the company follow button points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tandw.png) on [company pages](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/intuit), it shouldn't be sending the user there, only the form data representing your follow/ unfollow click.

Comment: I'm using a google chrome